# In water purification, if there are two carbon stages before the reverse osmosis (RO) stage, what exactly does a carbon stage after RO do?

Tags: water-purification

The usual note given by RO sellers is that the carbon stage after RO "improves taste". This is not thorough enough of an explanation for me, yet it's the only answer I can find on the internet.

Comment: When your question is closed for lack of details or clarity, edit it to add those, don't be the goofball who just asks the exact same question a few hours later. Clearly, you should take the [tour].

Comment: I edited the original and nothing happened